# Unsuccessfully trying to iteratively run gdal_polygonize in a batch file

Tags: gdal, batch, raster-conversion, polygonize, osgeo4w

Thanks in advance for your help with this.

I've been reading, experimenting, and banging my head against the wall for a couple days on this, and could really use some assistance. This is my first batch file attempt.

I'm trying to loop through .tif files in a folder and run a gdal process on them. I have been calling the .bat file via command line in the OsGeo4W terminal.

I can successfully run the gdal_polygonize process on individual files, but have not succeeded in running it iteratively.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET MYPATH = C:\Users\mkcarte2\Desktop\Polygonize\

FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B %MYPATH%*.tif') DO (

    SET MYPATHFILE=%%~nI ::Trying to parse only the filename, so that I don't stack extensions in the output file
    SET infile=%%i
    SET outfile=%MYPATHFILE%.shp!

    gdal_polygonize %MYPATH%!infile! -F  "ESRI Shapefile" %MYPATH%!outfile!
)
```

My Error Messages:

For first file:

> Warning 1: Layer name 'ESRI Shapefile' adjusted to >'ESRIShapefile'
>   for XML validity. Warning 1: Field name '%~nI.shp' adjusted to
>   '_nI.shp' to be a >valid XML element name.
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

For subsequent files:

> ERROR 4: `!infile!' does not exist in the file system, and is not
>   recognised as a supported dataset name. Unable to open !infile!

Comment: This appears to be a question about windows batch file work (parsing directories, striping filenames) rather than really having anything to do with GIS or gdal_polygonize. Perhaps it would be better on SuperUser?

Comment: Oops..  I'll relocate it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here

first there is SET VAR = VALUE - **no!** 
it's SET VAR=VALUE **no spaces!** when you follow SET VAR with a space it means unset var.

The exclamation marks are not batch that I've ever encountered. Variables are not case sensitive in batch but I like to capitalize so that I know what's going on.

Try this:

```
SET MYPATH=C:\Users\mkcarte2\Desktop\Polygonize\

FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR /B %MYPATH%\*.tif') DO (
::Trying to parse only the filename, so that I don't stack extensions in the output file
    SET MYPATHFILE=%%~nI
    SET infile=%%I
    SET outfile=%MYPATHFILE%.shp

    gdal_polygonize %MYPATH%\%infile% -F  "ESRI Shapefile" %MYPATH%\%outfile%
)
```

Comment: The exclamation marks are valid batch and are [required](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php) for delayed variable expansion.

Comment: That's a new one by me. I'll have to look that up, it could be quite useful.

Comment: Only if you _really_ want to work in batch... Ugggh ;)

Comment: It has it's uses, but they are becoming less frequent; a lot of the time it's easier to dir /b *.tif > list.csv then edit the csv in excel or alternately os.walk in python and os.system each line.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have incorporated it into the code, but am still having problems, as described in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works: Issues with your original code noted in comments.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

:: No spaces when SETting a var
SET MYPATH=C:\Users\mkcarte2\Desktop\Polygonize\

FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B %MYPATH%*.tif') DO (

    REM Trying to parse only the filename, so that 
    REM I don't stack extensions in the output file
    REM No inline comments after SET
    SET MYPATHFILE=%%~ni
    SET infile=%%i

    REM Your original code had a single ! after .shp 
    REM %MYPATHFILE% should be !MYPATHFILE! to Enable Delayed Expansion
    SET outfile=!MYPATHFILE!.shp

    REM lowercase "-f"! 
    REM add the layer name as last argument
    gdal_polygonize %MYPATH%!infile! -f  "ESRI Shapefile" %MYPATH%!outfile! !MYPATHFILE!
)
```

Note use of REM for multi-line comments as more than one :: on consecutive lines will cause a [`The system cannot find the drive specified.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843849/unexpected-the-system-cannot-find-the-drive-specified-in-batch-file) warning.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I edited the code in accordance with your suggestions, but still didn't get shapefiles.  I got the following "error" : 

gdal_polygonize [-8] [-nomask] [-mask filename] raster_file [-b band]
                [-q] [-f ogr_format] out_file [layer] [fieldname]

When I took out the layer name argument, I got the same results as before, i.e. gdal_polygonize appears to run through the first tiff, but the following images yield the "infile does not exist in system" error.

Comment: It may not solve the problem @Vergentorix but if you put echo in front of each of the lines that do something you will see the exact command that it issuing, that will help you find the line that has a problem. I suspect that the variable infile is not being replaced by its value.